# VSCode + F# : How to make "//#region" act like C# #region

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#

`//#region` appears in Intellisense, I wrapped some code:

```
//#region Graph
type AnnotationDataType =
    | Text
    | Image
    | Audio
    | Video

type Node =
    { NodeID: int
      NodeLabel: string
      AnnotationDataType: AnnotationDataType }

type Edge =
    { EdgeID: int
      EdgeLabel: string
      Source: int
      Target: int }

//#endregion
```

But nothing happens! I don't want regular "folding" since it often breaks (just try moving a line out of its scope..)

Clearly it exists: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics

Here is my config file, not much happening (I searched for properties related to region but found none relevant):

```
"[fsharp]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Ionide.Ionide-fsharp",
        "editor.codeLens": true,      
    },
```

edit: I've made a video showing the issue (bug appears around 30sec using Bisect) :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XthykOQlYUQ

edit: Open ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177051

Comment: nothing happens? you don't get a fold control in the gutter? it's documented behaviour though... if it's not working, it might be a bug.

Comment: That's right: no fold control/symbol in the gutter. 
Also, I find it strange that it looks like a simple "comment", it looks like VSCode treats it like it. Could you try on your side please? I updated to most recent VSCode version yesterday

Comment: works for me without using your settings. I'm on VS Code 1.76.1 Ubuntu. What if you remove your default-formatter setting?

Comment: tried to remove the setting but nothing; I've added an image in my initial post you can take a look. Which F# extension are you using (though I doubt that should influence VSCode behavior)? I'm only using Fantomas

*Also, my snippet is in a script file (fsx), but I tried to paste it in a "fs" file and same behaviour

Comment: I have no F# extensions. try doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect). Note: tried googling `site:github.com/fsprojects/fantomas/issues fold region` and got zero search results.

Comment: Found the issue using Bisect thank you for your help; It seems that Omnisharp is causing the bug. But now a new issue: I need Omnisharp too!

Comment: Damn.. not working again. so I guess it wasnt Omnisharp. I'll try to raise an issue to VSCode team thank you for your time.

Comment: @user I've added a video in my original post showing the bug using Bisect. What do you think it could be?

Comment: well... the bisect said it was the C# extension. I'm too lazy to try on my machine right now.